# HTML 5 Canvas, Edit and save on existing image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Being Super new to HTML 5 Canvas, I need to be able to load an image, and then be able to draw ie "hit points" on the image and save.

Ive only just started and can do this
[http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_drawimage.asp](https://web.archive.org/web/20120805002848/http://www.w3schools.com/html5/canvas_drawimage.asp)

so thats fine loading the image I just now need to allow the user to click on parts of the image to create dots and then be able to save them. Any good links or examples?

Answer (score 0):

Opera has a good tutorial on letting the user "paint" on the canvas: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/

Answer (score 0):

For the graphic editing of the dots there are IMO three main options:

1. load the image in a canvas and really change the canvas by drawing on it
2. load the image in an `img` and use it as a background over which there is a transparent canvas that is where you draw the dots
3. don't touch the image and don't use a canvas but make each dot a separate `img` tag that simply lives on top of the image

For sending the result you probably don't want to send over the modified image, but just the selected dot configuration and that is a normal ajax request to the server. It is also possible to send the modified image in `png` format (or even to "downloading" it locally on the computer without sending anything to the server), but that is IMO not an useful capability in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same, but you can achieve that. I can give you an headstart on this - checkout this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lakshaydulani/6Afy6/1/). I built this editor using [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com). The save functionality is also given in the NoteEditor.js

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement); 
canvas.add(imgInstance);//initialize the Canvas with the image
```